# Timer.schedule interval: does the interval time wait for the run method to be finish before restarting the interval?

Tags: java, timer

I have a `Timer` object created as such:

```
Timer timer = new Timer()
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doSomething();
    }
});
timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 10 * 1000);
```

This is a timer that will run every 10 seconds. What happens when the time needed to finish running `doSomething()` is bigger than the interval? Will the timer wait for `run()` to finish before starting the interval again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-)

> each execution is scheduled relative to the actual execution time of the previous execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), subsequent executions will be delayed as well

Without more details, I would suggest having a look at [`Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-)